# JQuery Passing Json value to textarea issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem passing a json value to a textarea.

This works:

```
alert(results.messages[0].text); //Result is Message 1

$("#myTextarea").val('Some Message'); //Adds Some Messsage to myTextarea
```

My problem is when I try this:

```
$("#myTextarea").val(results.messages[0].text);
```

This above does not add the value to the textarea.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Is your DOM ready when you try to set the value?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Why would that affect whether it works with a variable versus a literal string?

Comment: Yes, dom is ready ... don't understand why it only works with literal string :/

Comment: Is your code inside the `success:` function of the AJAX call?

Comment: seems to work in this https://jsfiddle.net/7x2whLwc/

Comment: @Barmar, I want to make sure whether he is dynamically adding that textarea or it is already defined in the HTML page.

Comment: Please post more code around the place where you try to add the value to the text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text` for text area. What you have should work. Don't forget to parse your JSON.

```
var results = '{"messages":[{"text":"some text from json"}]}'
results = JSON.parse(results);

$("textarea").text(results.messages[0].text);
```

Comment: Why doesn't he need to do that when he gives a literal string instead of a variable?

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, I'm not sure I get your question.

Comment: I don't want to add a string because it's a json value

Comment: The question says that it works when he does `.val("some message")`, but not when he does `.val(results.messages[0].text)`. How does your answer solve that?